# Issue updating list with a function

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        swim_d=int(input("Enter swimming distance(m): "))
        swim_s=float(input("Enter swimming speed(km/h): "))
        if swim_d<0 or swim_s<0:
            print('Please only enter positive numbers')
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please only enter positive numbers')

swimv=[['Cycle Shoes+Goggles',1.25],['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1], ['Run shoes+Goggles',1.33]
       ,['Run shoes+Sunglasses', 0.88], ['Flippers+Goggles',1.95], ['Flippers+SunGlasses',1.5]]

def update1(lst1):
    for i in lst1:
        i[1]*=swim_s

update1(swimv)

def update2(lst1): #calculate time
    global swim_d
    for i in lst1:
        swim_d/=i[1]
     
update2(swimv)
print(swimv)
```

The first function update1 works fine, but the second function doesn't change anything in the list it all, it keeps the same values from when update1() is appplied

Comment: You're not assigning to any values in the list in `update2`. Perhaps you meant `i[1]/=swim_d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't understand the problem

```py
while True:
    try:
        swim_d = int(input("Enter swimming distance(m): "))
        swim_s = float(input("Enter swimming speed(km/h): "))
        if swim_d < 0 or swim_s < 0:
            print('Please only enter positive numbers')
        else:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print('Please only enter positive numbers')

swimv = [['Cycle Shoes+Goggles', 1.25], ['Cycle shoes+Sunglasses', 1], ['Run shoes+Goggles', 1.33],
         ['Run shoes+Sunglasses', 0.88], ['Flippers+Goggles', 1.95], ['Flippers+SunGlasses', 1.5]]


def update1(lst1):
    for i in lst1:
        i[1] *= swim_s
    return lst1


swimv = update1(swimv)
print(swimv)


def update2(lst1, swim_d):  # calculate time
    _ = list()
    for i in lst1:
        _.append([i[0], i[1] / swim_d])
    return _


swimv_2 = update2(swimv, swim_d)
print(swimv_2)
```